# How to make callback from AsyncTask to fragment Activity?

Tags: java, android

I have requests to web service implemented using AsyncTask. Normally callback to Activity i do using interface:

```
public interface AsyncTaskComplete<T> {

    public void onTaskComplete(T result);
    public void onTaskFailed(T result);

}
```

In AsyncTask:

```
private AsyncTaskComplete<String> callback;

public AsyncTaskAbout(AsyncTaskComplete<String> cb) {
    this.callback = cb;
}

protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    if(result ==  null){
        callback.onTaskFailed(result);
    }else{
        callback.onTaskComplete(result);
    }

}
```

But if i want to give callback FragmentActivity compiler suggest me to change AsyncTask constructor to:

```
public AsyncTaskAbout(FragmentActivity faActivity) {
    this.callback = (AsyncTaskComplete<String>) faActivity;
}
```

Where is warning:

```
Type safety: Unchecked cast from FragmentActivity to AsyncTaskComplete<String>
```

So what i need to change ?

Or how to make callback in this case ?

Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you pass the `FragmentActivity` as a second parameter to the constructor? Like `public AsyncTaskAbout(AsyncTaskComplete<String> cb, FragmentActivity faActivity)`

Comment: Are you sure you made the relevant `FragmentActivity` implement your interface?